# In What Order to Practice Holding Notes on Bansuri

Tags: scales, indian-classical, bansuri

At the start of Bansuri practice, I try to blow each note and hold as long as possible. I do this 6 times per note, i.e. `Sa Re Ga Ma Pa Dha Ni SA`

But now I realize there are three octaves in Bansuri

My question is, in what order should I practice.

On one hand, everything starts with middle octave `Sa`, so I can practice

`Sa Re Ga Ma Pa Dha Ni SA RE GA MA PA`

but what about lower octaves `pa da ni`?

What is recommended order (per Bansuri Gurus, experienced Bansuri players, or even experts in Indian classical music) for blowing each note the longest?

[image: Courtesy of http://www.bansuriflute.co.uk/p/bansuri-fingering-chart.html]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to cover as many notes as you can, starting from `pa`. After `pa` you should go up, like this: `pa da ni Sa Re Ga Ma Pa Dha Ni SA RE GA MA PA`. If you do it this, way you will cover two octaves.

Comment: Interesting. Several places say Bansuri has two octaves, others say three. Technically speaking, it covers 3 octaves, but it is slightly more than 2 octaves!